# Allow php script access only from Android client

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to call a php script from my android app to pass some data and store it in the database. Is there a way to allow access to php script from my android client only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NO, The only thing that has information about the client is HTTP User Agent that will be sent within HTTP Request header, but header information must not be used for security because header can be faked and changed, therefore, you can depend on unique parameter (public not private) to be sent to your PHP server from Android client, for example send Unique Identifier with all request such as (page.php?android=UNIQUE_ID) then you can check this identifier from your PHP script. Again, this approach is also not secure and not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `accessToken` in every `httpRequest`, and server will identify that `accessToken` & will respond appropriately.

Comment: Can you please suggest any link that does that? how secure is this approach?

Comment: Many of the apps works this way, I have used this approach in many cases.Regarding security - any one who has `accessToken` can use your API, so better to keep it private.

Comment: Cant give you tuts for that, but you can proceed this way - 1. Add `accessToken` (some random string) in every `httpRequest` either as param or in request header. 2. On server side get this `accessToken`, if its valid process the request otherwise return error.